# Keyboard view gets messed up with Modally presented view using UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, swift

I'm presenting a view from another using a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` instance as `transitioning delegate and modalPresentationStyle = Custom`.
I'm using a `TableViewController` using static table view cells with `UITextfields` inside. Now when tapping over a text field whose borders are close to the the keyboard's frame, part of the tableView beneath the keyboard shows up. I also removed a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that I added to the semi-transparent background to make sure it's not part of the problem but the issue it's still there. Any ideas? Below is the `animateTransition()` method

```
  func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
if let presentedViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) {

    let presentedView = presentedViewController.view
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    let centre = presentedView.center

    if isPresenting {

        presentedView.center = containerView.center
        presentedView.frame = presentedView.bounds.rectByInsetting(dx: 30, dy: 150)

        transitionContext.containerView().addSubview(presentedView)

        dimmingView.frame = containerView.bounds
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        containerView.insertSubview(dimmingView, atIndex: 0)

        presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({
            context in
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    else {
        presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({
            context in
            self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: {
                context in
                self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }



    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext),
        delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0, options: nil,
        animations: {
            presentedView.center = centre
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })
}

}
```

[image]